# Consuming RESTfull api using spring for android or using Virgil Dobjanschi pattern discussed in google io

Tags: java, android

I am learning how to consume or use REST full api for mobile using java.

There are many options available.However can any one tell which one is better in both of them ?

1. using spring for android
2. Virgil Dobjanschi pattern discussed in google io 2010

and is there any other more good then both is available ? Any links and sample code will be helpfull

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some difference between the two.

Virgil Dobjanschi talked about issues like getting the response from webservice even when the activity is closed or destroyed, which the Springs for android doesn't address.

He also talked about storing the results in the database and making it in-sync with the server. Which was not addressed in spring for android.

Spring for android, creates a separate non-UI thread and gets the data into the bean.

Both have their own space. So we can still follow his pattern and use spring for android as well.

Comment: You can also try volley framework mentioned in Google IO. I think it ll replace both.

Answer (score 1):

How about using [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/) rest client, here is the sample code for the same taken from : http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/restful-java-client-with-jersey-client/

```
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;

public class JerseyClientPost {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {

        Client client = Client.create();

        WebResource webResource = client
           .resource("http://localhost:8080/RESTfulExample/rest/json/metallica/post");

        String input = "{\"singer\":\"Metallica\",\"title\":\"Fade To Black\"}";

        ClientResponse response = webResource.type("application/json")
           .post(ClientResponse.class, input);

        if (response.getStatus() != 201) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                 + response.getStatus());
        }

        System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
        String output = response.getEntity(String.class);
        System.out.println(output);

      } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

      }

    }
}
```

Comment: Is it related to android?

Comment: @NareshR This is a generic rest client code using jersey libs, and works well with android!